# Python-firebase library gives exception

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

When i use python-firebase library, i trying to login with my email and password ( all in firebase is on), i set rules write and read to "auth!=null" for security, and me need get all data. So i use this code which not work.

```
from firebase import firebase
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseAuthentication
import json
print("Load old session?:(y/n)")
oldnew = input()
if (oldnew == "n"):
    print("Write Email to sign in:")
    email = input()
    print("Write password to sign in:")
    password = input()
    data = {
        "email": email,
        "password": password
        }
    with open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyFiles/datafordb.txt", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile)
else:
    with open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\PyFiles/datafordb.txt", "r") as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        password = data.get("password")
        email = data.get("email")
authentication = FirebaseAuthentication(password, email, False, False)
firebase.authentication = authentication
user = authentication.get_user()
print(user.firebase_auth_token)
uid = 'wZExtuMB6IX0N5Bx3G5Q7gm053f1'
fb = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://theannouncer-6998a.firebaseio.com/', None)
result = fb.get('theannouncer-6998a/', None)
print(result)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\readnoauthFirebase(FAIL).py", line 28, in <module>
    result = fb.get('theannouncer-6998a/', None)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\firebase\decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\firebase\firebase.py", line 274, in get
    return make_get_request(endpoint, params, headers, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\firebase\decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\firebase\firebase.py", line 42, in make_get_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 862, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://theannouncer-6998a.firebaseio.com/theannouncer-6998a/.json
```

Comment: What doesn't work about this code when you run it? Which specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: edited my question, added error